# Running a docker image through Vagrant

Tags: docker, vagrant, vagrantfile

My `Vagrantfile` is is set to run a docker image we will call `gitlab/gitlab-ce`

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "centos/7"
  config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
     d.run "gitlab/gitlab-ce"
  end
end
```

Running `vagrant provision` gives me:

> Unable to find image 'gitlab/gitlab-ce' locally

Why can it not find my `gitlab/gitlab-ce` locally?

When I do a `docker ps -a` I see that `gitlab/gitlab-ce` is up and running just fine

Answer (score 1):

Because `docker ps` lists active containers not images. You need to use a publicly available image or run

`docker images`

To see images available and built on your machine

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have clarified. `example_image` is a valid image I see whene I do a `docker images`

Comment: Can you share the full vagrant file and the output of 
docker images | grep {actual_image_name} ?

Comment: added full Vagrantfile. Am I correct in thinking I can simply just do a .run and I don't need to pull or build images first with Vagrant?